# Error The manifest must contain exactly one "description" tags

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently try to build a package for standalone ROS node in MATLAB Simulink. I've followed the instructions perfectly until build catkin workspace step.

```
dinhthong@dinhthong-Inspiron-3542:~/USV_ws2$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/dinhthong/USV_ws2
Source space: /home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/src
Build space: /home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/build
Devel space: /home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/devel
Install space: /home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/dinhthong/catkin_ws/devel;/home/dinhthong/kinetic/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/dinhthong/catkin_ws/devel;/home/dinhthong/kinetic/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.12") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/build/test_results
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
CMake Error at /home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake:2 (message):
  The manifest must contain exactly one "description" tags
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:42 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:63 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/dinhthong/USV_ws2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I failed sereval times finding work around for this problem, but still...!
I use ROS Kinetic in Ubuntu 16.04. Many thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281015/error-the-manifest-must-contain-exactly-one-%22description%22-tags/) by [dinhthong](https://answers.ros.org/users/33446/dinhthong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `package.xml` is probably missing or has an extra `<description>` tag. Either add the missing or delete the extra tag(s).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinhthong](https://answers.ros.org/users/33446/dinhthong/) on 2018-01-27**:
that isn't the case. This workspace "**USV_ws2**" is duplicated from USV_ws and the original **USV_ws** is built successfully.
When I duplicated USV_ws to USV_ws2 I also deleted 2 folders build and devel. And then catkin_make again. Then this error happens.